# simple push notification in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I have a project that is related to job postings. Consultants or employers register on my website and then start posting jobs. I want to make push notifications for all users.  When a consultant or employer posts a job, all online users must get notified that an employer has posted this job without any page refreshes on jquery setInterval or timeout.

I am using Spring framework. I have searched for the solution but found nothing. I want to know whether Spring provided WebSockets in their latest version. Is this possible to do with WebSockets?

I want a proper resource so that I can implement it on my website.

Comment: you need polling (also check long polling) if you are using spring version less than 4, for 4 (along with tomcat 8) you also have websockets for real push.

Comment: can you provide me example code resource so that i can implement with the help of Web Socket spring 4

Comment: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat good example for that

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to satisfy your need;

First is `polling` in which you repeatedly send requests from client to the server. On server side you somehow need have a kind of message queue for each client to deliver the incidents on a request. There also is a different type of polling in which you send a request from client and never end the request on the server-side thus you have a kind of pipe between two ends. This is called `long polling`.
Disadvantage of polling is that you have to send requests to the server forever from the client and in many cases server sends empty messages as there is no events happened.

The real application of pushing messages is recently avaliable with websockets (thanks to html5). However this requires the application server to be capable of websocket functionality. afaik jetty and tomcat has this ability. Spring 4 has websocket here you can find the tutorial; http://syntx.io/using-websockets-in-java-using-spring-4/

You can find a related stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)